# GDB, python scripting to get return values from a function

Tags: python, gdb

I am trying to get value of gdb call command to a python variable using python scripting support.

### My Script

```
import gdb

res = []
res.append(gdb.execute("call factorial(4)"))
res.append(gdb.execute("call factorial(5)"))
print res
```

### Output

```
$4 = 24
$5 = 120
[None, None]
```

Anything that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Exact duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986589/how-to-get-output-from-gdb-execute-in-pythongdb-gdb-7-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the linked question, it looks like you are missing a few flags. Does

```
import gdb

res = []
res.append(gdb.execute("call factorial(4)", False, True))
res.append(gdb.execute("call factorial(5)", False, True))
print res
```

work?  [(doc)](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html#Basic-Python)